# How to create a instance that have Fk on User with factory boy?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, factory-boy

I'm trying to mock a resource objects that have a `FK` for the User model, but when i instantiate the class o got the error:

```
bf = BenefitFactory()
```

> AttributeError: type object 'UserFactory' has no attribute '_meta'

The factories:

```
class UserFactory:
    class Meta:
        model = User

    first_name = factory.Faker('first_name')
    last_name = factory.Faker('last_name')
    username = factory.Faker('email')
    password = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: make_password('pi3.1415'))
    is_staff = False
    is_superuser = False


class BenefitFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Benefit

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
```

I've also tried to use the method `RelatedFactory` like this:

```
class BenefitFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Benefit

    user = factory.RelatedFactory(UserFactory, 'user')
```

But then i got the error saying:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

How can i create a `Benefit` objects with an User related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error comes from the fact that your `UserFactory` doesn't inherit from `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory`!

For the second, the `RelatedFactory` runs **after** saving the `Benefit` to the database; but since your `Benefit` model has a `ForeignKey` to `User`, you *MUST* provide an instance of `User` when creating the `Benefit` — which is done using a `SubFactory`, as in your initial version!

So, the fix is simply:

```py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...


class BenefitFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
```